# Set height of all divs uniformly

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, dropdown

I have a drop-down with slide-up and slide-down animation inside a div.

When the drop down is open, the div's height is `124px` else its `20px`. I have another div, for which height should be equal to that of the first div even, when animating the height of div's drop-down.

I am using jquery 1.11.0

Here is my code:

```
$( ".dropdown" ).hide();
$('.title').on('click', function(){
  var element = $(".dropdown");
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
    element.removeClass('open');
    element.slideUp();
  }
  else {
    element.addClass('open');
    element.slideDown();
  }
});
```

[here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/5zvk23gw/1/).

What can I do?

**Edit:**
I only want the height to be same for both the div's at all times.

When `div 1` height is changing the js/jQuery should set the same height to `div 2`.

```js
$(".dropdown").hide();
$('.title').on('click', function() {
  var element = $(".dropdown");
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
    element.removeClass('open');
    element.slideUp();
  } else {
    element.addClass('open');
    element.slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
.d1 {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.d2 {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d1">
  <a class="title">title(click here)</a>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="d2">
  <a>victim</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the second div also to have a drop-down, is that it?

Comment: @Ani please see the question for 2nd time.

Comment: Height of both the divs are `20px`. Check the fiddle.

Comment: yes, height of both the divs are 20px. I want, when div 1 height extend, at the same time and with same animation 2nd div will extend. But,  not the drop-down. 2nd div will be blank except the text "victim"(I am trying to understand you that i dont need any content of 1st div. only extend the height with animation).

Comment: I think @Rohit has put up working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfect for you:

```
var slideDown = $("#d1").height();
$( ".dropdown" ).hide();
var slideUp = $("#d1").height();
$('.title').on('click', function(){
  var element = $(".dropdown");
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
    element.removeClass('open');

    element.slideUp(400, function(){});
    $("#d2").animate({height:  slideUp}, 500);

  }
  else {
    element.addClass('open');
    element.slideDown(400, function(){});
    $("#d2").animate({height:  slideDown}, 500);

  }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zvk23gw/15/)**

Comment: Thanks @Rohit for your answer. It works as i wanted except animation. I want animation in 2nd div like 1st div.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit for your effort. Every thing is OK. Except 2nd div,s animation happens after 1st div,s animation is finished.I need both at same time. They should look like they both extend at the same time and collapse at  the same time.

Comment: @Shohidul, I have update code, it is works perfectly which you need. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".dropdown" ).hide();
$('.title').on('click', function(){
  var element = $(".dropdown");
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
    element.removeClass('open');    
    element.slideUp();
      -get the height of the dropdown 
    // var elHeight = $('.dropdown').css('height') + 'px';
     -apply height to other div
    // $('.otherdiv').css("height",elHeight)
  }
  else {
    element.addClass('open');
    element.slideDown();
    // var elHeight = $('.dropdown').css('height') + 'px';
    // $('.otherdiv').css("height",elHeight);
  }
});
```

Comment: Put up a working code. This one doesn't work and has no explanation.